# Verbs for when asking someone(e.g designer) to do a job(logo design) for you for a fee

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I would like to use a verb to describe the above situation. There are many professions like consultants,web designers which charge fees on project basis.

Example answer for above question would be :

I **assign** Max(freelance designer) to design a logo for my new coffee shop at 100$.

Are there any more fitting verbs other than assign to describe the situation?
The closest word I found to describe is **consign** but it isn't expressive enough for what I would like to say.

Comment: Does "commissioned" work for you?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you need an article before _logo_.

Comment: @deadrat yeah, I thought of it before. What I would like to know from this question is to get other verbs for usage in this situtation. Thanks

Comment: Consult, contract, and hire come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word is ***engage***

> [with object] Arrange to employ or hire (someone):
>   *he was engaged as a trainee copywriter*
>
> [with infinitive] Pledge or enter into a contract to do something:
>   *he engaged to pay them £10,000 against a bond*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/engage)

You *engaged* Max to design your logo.

Or possibly ***contract***

> [with object and infinitive] Impose an obligation on (someone) to do something by means of a formal agreement:
>   *health authorities contract a hospital to treat a specific number of patients*
>
> [no object] Enter into a formal and legally binding agreement:
>   *the local authority will contract with a wide range of agencies to provide services*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract)

You *contracted* Max to design your logo.
You *contracted with* Max to design your logo.

Comment: Or just "hired"

Comment: @DaleM Why not make that an answer? I didn't include it because it's not usually used in the UK: we hire cars, not people.

Comment: @DaleM "Hired" may be used in some quarters, but the distinction between being engaged (as a consultant or freelancer) and being hired (as an employee) can be an extremely important one.

Answer (score 2):

How about *enlist*? Maybe this sounds better than *assign*?

Answer (score 0):

**Hire**

is the most common way to say this in the U.S.  (*Engage* could be used, but might make you sound a bit pompous.)